# React js: Image upload is not working in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ckeditor

CKEditor image upload is not working and below is the code

```
<CKEditor
                    editor={ ClassicEditor }
                    data={this.state.miscNotesData.miscnote}
                    onInit={ editor => {
                        // You can store the "editor" and use when it is needed.
                        console.log( 'Editor is ready to use!', editor );
                    } }
                    onChange={ ( event, editor ) => {
                        const data = editor.getData();
                        this.handleChange(data);
                        console.log( { event, editor, data } );
                    } }

                />
```

Error:

```
  backend.js:6 filerepository-no-upload-adapter: Upload adapter is not defined. 
Read more: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/support/error-codes.html#error-filerepository-no-upload-adapter
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As provided in documentation https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/image-upload/image-upload.html
there are 4 options to upload images in CKEDitor: Easy Image(proprietary), CKFinder(needs connector on PHP or ASP.net), Simple adapter, Base64 adapter

I use Simple adapter for this purpose with Node js server:

First, I installed SimpleUploadAdapter in ClassicEditor, then I set up config in CKEditor:

```
   <CKEditor
        data={input.value}
        editor={ ClassicEditor }
        config={{
          simpleUpload: {
            uploadUrl: 'https://myserver.herokuapp.com/image-upload'
          },
          toolbar: ['heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'blockQuote', 'link', 'numberedList', 'bulletedList', 'imageUpload', 'insertTable',
            'tableColumn', 'tableRow', 'mergeTableCells', 'mediaEmbed', '|', 'undo', 'redo']
        }}
      />
```

And create url on my server /image-upload

Comment: Thanks for your update. 

Even after adding the simple adapter its giving me the same error.
Here is the Code Snippet:
       <CKEditor

                    editor={ ClassicEditor}
                    config={{
                   simpleUpload: {
                     uploadUrl: 'C:\Attachment_Migration'
                   },
                   toolbar: ['heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 
                     'tableColumn', 'tableRow', 'mergeTableCells', 'mediaEmbed', '|', 'undo', 'redo']
                   }}

                   >

Comment: How did you add SimpleUploadAdapter in classic editor? And what is C:\Attachment_Migration - upload Url?

Answer (score 0):

you can use extraPlugins options..
To use it, you can fine their document.
At config, you will set extraPlugins .
you can make uploadPlugin function to work it.

```html
 <CKEditor
                    editor={ ClassicEditor }
                    config = {{
                        placeholder : "please your question, here",
                        extraPlugins: [uploadPlugin] 
                    }}
```